# How to save a file from jersey response?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am trying to download a SWF file using Jersey from a web resource.

I have written the following code, but am unable to save the file properly :

```
Response response = webResource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
  .cookie(cookie)
  .post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE));

String binarySWF = response.readEntity(String.class);                                     
byte[] SWFByteArray = binarySWF.getBytes();       

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("myfile.swf"));
fos.write(SWFByteArray);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

It is save to assume that the response does return a SWF file, as `response.getMediaType` returns `application/x-shockwave-flash`.

However when I try to open the SWF, nothing happen (also no error) which suggest that my file was not created from response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Java 7 on, you can also make use of the new NIO API to write the input stream to a file:

```
InputStream is = response.readEntity(InputStream.class)
Files.copy(is, Paths.get(...));
```

Comment: `response.getEntity()` doesn't accept parameters (at least in jersey-client 2.26). Maybe you meant `response.readEntity(InputStream.class)`?

Comment: I cannot test it right now, but according to the Javadoc you are right. I have updated the answer. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 7):

I've finally got it to work.

I figured out reading the Jersey API that I could directly use `getEntity` to retrieve the InputStream of the `response` (assuming it has not been read yet).

Using `getEntity` to retrieve the `InputStream` and `IOUtils#toByteArray` which create a byte array from an `InputStream`, I managed to get it to work :

```
Response response = webResource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
  .cookie(cookie)
  .post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE));                                                  

InputStream input = (InputStream)response.getEntity();

byte[] SWFByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);  

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("myfile.swf"));
fos.write(SWFByteArray);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Note that [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) is a common Apache function.

Comment: converting input stream into byte array throws System.out.of memory , not a good solution

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not go through a String at all.

If the response is really the SWF file (binary data), then here:

```
String binarySWF = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

instead of this code (which reads a String), just try reading 
a byte array. See if it helps. Strings are related to encodings
and probably that messes things up.